# latex-suite F9 completion key works in gvim but not in vim

Tags: vim, latex-suite

I am setting up a latex-suite environment for my vim. I discovered that the F9 key that is used to complete references (be them \ref{ or \cite{) only works when I edit the file in gvim (showing that the setup is correct) but not in vim (konsole or xterm terminals tested). Has anybody experienced such a situation? How could one fix this problem ? Thanks a lot for your help.
~~~ 
 
System: 
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 in a Debian GNU/Linux box

Comment: You can verify that the key is mapped with `:map <F9>`. This probably has to do with your terminal emulator. What do you get when you press `<C-v><F9>` in insert mode? This should show the key code that Vim receives (`^[[20~` in my `xterm`, where `^[` is the escape character).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :map <F9> did not yield anything ("No mapping found") in both configs (vim and gvim). However, <C-v><F9> displayed fine in gvim, while it produced this string in term: "^[[20~" (like happens with you). To check if the software understand fine that key, I issued :nnoremap <F9> gg. And that worked fine: pressing <F9> would go to the top of the file. So I am not yet done with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in the `vimrc`. I had `set paste` in there and after I removed it, F9 would work again.

If you want to find out, if it is related to the `vimrc`, you can create another one and use that one with `vim -u ~/.vimrc_latex`